# Jekyll Localhost different

Tags: localhost, jekyll

- I forked the Contract Jekyll Theme, it renders properly in username.github.io, example I added the latest.md but doesnt render in localhost what could be the issue.

**_config.yml
navigation:                # accepts {file, title, url, icon, sidebaricon}

- {file: "index.html", title:"Home"}
- {file: "README.md", title:"About"}
- {file: "latest.md", title:"Blogs"}
- 2 Can we have custom folders and use them in the file like
- {file: "/articles/article.md", title:"Articles"}
  No Errors in username.github.io but the navigation link doesnt render both in localhost and on gihub.io

navigation:                # accepts {file, title, url, icon, sidebaricon}

- {file: "index.html", title:"Home"}
- {file: "README.md", title:"About"}
- {file: "latest.md", title:"Blogs"}